# GridLayout and width

Tags: android

I'm creating a GridLayout with a number of buttons inside it.

I want the width of the GridLayout to match the device screen, but i don't know if i should menage the width of the GridLayout or the witdhs of the buttons that are inside the GridLayout.

I add buttons to the GridLayout dynamically. Sometimes the buttons might needs more space than the space the screen gives them! That's why i don't know how to menage it.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is the GridLayout to match the Devices width I would set the layout XML to:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".GridActivity" >

     <GridLayout
         android:id="@+id/button_grid"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
     </GridLayout> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I add buttons to the GridLayout dynamically. Sometimes the buttons might needs more space than the spece the screen gives them! That why i dunno how to menage it

Comment: Seeing as your using a GridLayout you would probably benefit from using a fixed columnCount, and place your buttons one within each column row. Additionally you may want to set the layout_gravity to fill_horizontal if your buttons have varying widths

Comment: I have fixed columnCount, and i tried to set the Gridlayout width according to the screen width, but I couldn't. I tried using `GridLayout.LayoutParams`, `setWidth` etc.. but nothing happens